# Special char Literals

Tags: c, gcc, char, literals

I want to assign a char with a char literal, but it's a special character say 255 or 13.
I know that I can assign my char with a literal int that will be cast to a char: `char a = 13;`
I also know that Microsoft will let me use the [hex code as a char literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6aw8xdf2.aspx): `char a = '\xd'`

I want to know if there's a way to do this that gcc supports also.

Comment: What makes you think those methods are not cross-platform?

Comment: Which platforms are you concerned about? Are you talking about different compilers, or different OSs, or different character sets?

Comment: The character whose code is `13` in ascii is correctly written as `'\r'`, which is completely portable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hexidecimal escape sequence is *not* specific to Microsoft. It's part of C/C++: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape

Meaning that to assign a hexidecimal number to a `char`, this *is* cross platform code:

```
char a = '\xD';
```

The question already demonstrates assigning a decimal number to a `char`:

```
char a = 13;
```

And octal numbers can also be assigned as well, with only the escape switch:

```
char a = '\023';
```

Incidentally, `'\0'` is common in C/C++ to represent the null-character (independent of platform). `'\0'` is not a special character that can be escaped. That's actually invoking the octal escape sequence.

Comment: "It's part of C/C++" -- More precisely, it's part of C and it's part of C++. But the question was just tagged C, so I'm not sure C++ is relevant.

Comment: @Keith Thompson 2nd that as the languages also have differences in type:  In C `sizeof('\xD') == sizeof (int)` whereas in C++ `sizeof('\xD') == sizeof (char)`

Comment: @chux Oh snap, I didn't know that. Does that mean all literal `char`s are interpreted as `int`s in C? So it always has to convert back to a `char` to assign?

Comment: Yes, in C, since `'\xD'` is an `int`, it is narrowed as needed when assigned to a `char`.

Answer (score 1):

Writing something like

```
char ch = 13;
```

is *mostly* portable, to platforms on which the value `13` is the same thing as on your platform (which is all systems which uses the ASCII character set, which indeed is most systems today).

There may be platforms on which `13` can mean something else. However, using `'\r'` instead should always be portable, no matter the character encoding system.

Using other values, which does not have character literal equivalents, are *not* portable. And using values above 127 is even *less* portable, since then you're outside the ASCII table, and into the *extended ASCII table*, in which the letters can depend on the locale settings of the system. For example, western European and eastern European language settings will most likely have different characters in the `128` to `255` range.

If you want to use a *byte* which can contain just some binary data and not letters, instead of using `char` you might be wanting to use e.g. `uint8_t`, to tell other readers of your code that you're not using the variable for letters but for binary data.